# Saving a Newly Created Eloquent Model as a Job Property Prevents the Job from Being Handled

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, jobs

I have a Laravel job that is supposed to accept a newly created Eloquent model as a constructor attribute, then perform a save() operation on it in the handle() method. However, as soon as I try saving the model to the private property, the handle() method is not executed anymore. Here's the code:

MyController.php:

```
$category = new Category;
SaveModelJob::dispatch($category);
```

SaveModelJob.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SaveModelJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $model;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($model)
    {
        //
        dump('saving as property'); // this gets executed
        $this->model = $model; // <--- PROBLEMATIC CODE
        dump('saved as property'); // this also gets executed
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        dump("handling"); // <--- This stops being executed as soon as the PROBLEMATIC CODE above is added
        // a $this->model->save() operations is intended here
        

    }
}
```

In my real controller, some Model attributes are set before passing the $category to the SaveModelJob, but for simplicity's sake, I've removed most of the irrelevant code. To get some of the possible issues out of the way:

- The Category model is a simple Eloquent model
- I have QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync set in my .env and the handle() method actually gets executed if the problematic code is not there, so I don't think the problem is directly related to the queue
- If I pass an existing Category object from the database instead of newly created (but not saved) one, the handle() method is reached.
- I am using Laravel 8.34.

I have a suspicion that the Job object does not act like a regular class and the handle() method is reached much later, outside of the initial request lifecycle and this might have implications in the way the private property is accessed at a later time (especially when the queue driver is not "sync", but say, Redis), but I get no such errors in the log.

Do you know what the issue can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you dispatch an object to the queue, the object will be saved into the queue, but if you’re passing an Eloquent Model, it will be referenced from the Database by its id (or primary key) instead of being saved entirely into the payload

To avoid that using an unsavec model, just send it as an array.

Controller

```php
$category = new Category;
SaveModelJob::dispatch($category->toArray()); //or build the array from scratch
```

SaveModelJob

```
public function __construct($model)
{
    //
    dump('saving as property');
    $this->model = Category::make($model);
    dump('saved as property');
}
```

If you use the same script for all your models, add another attribute for the class

Controller

```php
$category = new Category;
SaveModelJob::dispatch($category->toArray(), Category::class); //or build the array from scratch
```

SaveModelJob

```
public function __construct($model, $eloquentClass)
{
    //
    dump('saving as property');
    $this->model = $eloquentClass::make($model);
    dump('saved as property');
}
```

Comment: I suspected something like this is happening and ended up with a solution that looks almost exactly like what you're suggesting. It works like a charm! I'm accepting your answer for the great insight into how the queues work and the solution that perfectly fits the use case, also being generic enough to be used with any other model. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you have saved your model. Please create or save your model, then send it to  job:

```php
$category->save();
```

Also to make sure correct model is passed to job, it's better to inject model:

```php
    public function __construct(Category $category)
    {
        $this->model= $category;
    }
```

But it still works if you don't inject model class.

Comment: That is correct, I'm not saving the model and I'm doing that on purpose (I'm trying to send the DB writes to a fast queue, instead of writing them directly - not a final solution, but I'm experimenting with this). Also, I did not want to inject any particular model, because I wanted to use the same class for saving any model using the queue, to even out the traffic spikes over time. I've ended up sending the attributes and the class name to the job instead. Thanks for your input, it pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome. That's it, so you need to pass the attributes to job class let it save the model. But keep in mind your job connection needs to be faster than database so that what you're gonna do be reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick, we can pass objects as array of objects and it will be saved in payload fully)